# JTable TableCellRenderer not coloring correctly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have created a simple `JTable` with my custom `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. On its own it is working fine (coloring last column). But as soon as I select a row OR filter/unfilter it, the row is colored, even if it shouldn't be colored at all.

My renderer:

```
public class StatusCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int col) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), col);
        DataTableModel model = (DataTableModel) table.getModel();
        String data = model.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), col).toString();
        if (col == 3 && data.equalsIgnoreCase("successful") && !data.isEmpty()) {
            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        if (col == 3 && !data.equalsIgnoreCase("successful") && !data.isEmpty()) {
            c.setBackground(new Color(255, 51, 51));
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

How it initially looks (and how it always should look):

[image]

And after selecting 2 rows (the top and bottom one):

[image]

As you can see, there are a few rows GREEN, which shouldn't be colored at all. Whats even more disturbing is the fact that I only selected the top and bottom row of the green block, which means that it automatically also colors the rows in between.

**How can I stop this behavior and only color the rows as shown in the first picture?**

---

The accepted answer helped me very much to overcome the issues and this is the final code:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int col) {
    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
            table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), table.convertColumnIndexToModel(col));
    DataTableModel model = (DataTableModel) table.getModel();
    String data = model.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(row), table.convertColumnIndexToModel(col))
            .toString();
    if (!isSelected) {
        if (col == 3 && data.equalsIgnoreCase("successful") && !data.isEmpty()) {
            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if (col == 3 && !data.equalsIgnoreCase("successful") && !data.isEmpty()) {
            c.setBackground(new Color(255, 51, 51));
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    } else {
        c.setBackground(c.getBackground());
    }
    return c;
}
```

It colors blue if the cell is selected and if not, then it colors WHITE, GREEN or RED depending on the value

Comment: As a quick guess, I'd point at the super call. You are converting the rowIndex to the modelIndex when calling `super.getTableCellRendererComponent` which might lead to the wrong component being returned and then colored.

Comment: @MalteHartwig I already used `row` without converting it and it didn't change anything. Actually that was my initial approach. If I try to debug it, it also colors every cell GREEN that is not colored RED

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but I'm seeing you convert the row index to a model index but not the column index. Note that if the columns in the view are reordered (or hidden/not shown) that you will see strangeness. Best to convert both row and column indices. I'm assuming the `3` is a particular model index, not a view index.

Comment: @TT. I have reordering disabled so I can just use that column all the way. Yet i changed it to convert both values to model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the renderer component will be re-used, consider setting a default color when no condition match :

```
    if (col == 3 && data.equalsIgnoreCase("successful") && !data.isEmpty()) {
        c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if (col == 3 && !data.equalsIgnoreCase("successful") && !data.isEmpty()) {
        c.setBackground(new Color(255, 51, 51));
    }
    else {
        c.setBackground(Color.GRAY.brighter());
    }
```

Comment: I modified a bit and it works pretty good now, except that if the cell is already coloured, then I can't color it in the blueish style when it gets selected. Any idea around that? Pretty much the selection color should have precedence over everything else, but as soon as it looses the selection, it should color after the rules I already have

Comment: From your edited question, it seems that you have found the way to do that ?